# Er sagt dass er mich liebe / liebt?

Tags: grammatical-case, grammaticality

Ich möchte gerne wissen ob es in diesem Satz richtig wäre die beiden Formen zu benutzen, und ob hier "liebe" zu benutzen eher unnatüralich/merkwürdig in umgangssprache klingen würde. Danke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es kommt auf den Sprachverwendungskontext an.

In einem formlosen Alltagsgespräch würde man eher

> Er sagt, dass er mich liebt

sagen, und die Verwendung des Konjunktivs wäre überkandidelt oder würde - wie Panta Rei schon schrieb - möglicherweise andeuten, dass der Sprecher an der Wahrhaftigkeit der Aussage zweifelt.

In einem Roman mit gepflegter Sprache dagegen würde man schreiben:

> Claus und Angela gingen im Wald spazieren. Als sie auf eine Lichtung kamen, wo die Vorabendsonne durch die Wipfel blitzte, nahm Claus Angela an die Hand, sah ihr in die grünen Augen und sagte ihr, dass er sie liebe.

Hier "dass er sie liebt" zu schreiben, geht einfach nicht. Jeder halbwegs brauchbare Lektor würde es anstreichen.

---

PS

Kommentator Carsten merkt an, dass mein Kurzroman nicht im Präsens geschrieben sei. Probieren wir es also mit einer Erzählung im Präsens:

> Claus und Angela gehen im Wald spazieren. Sie kommen auf eine Lichtung, wo die Vorabendsonne durch die Fichtenwipfel blitzt. Da nimmt Claus Angela bei der  Hand, sieht ihr in die dunkelblauen Augen und sagt ihr, **dass er sie liebt**.
>
> Claus und Angela gehen im Wald spazieren. Sie kommen auf eine Lichtung, wo die Vorabendsonne lustig durch die Wipfel blitzt. Da nimmt Claus Angela bei der  Hand, sieht ihr in die braunen Augen und sagt ihr, **dass er sie liebe**.

Ein interessanter Fall. Für mein Gefühl sind beide Varianten akzeptabel. Da die Geschichte im Präsens geschrieben ist und dadurch an Unmittelbarkeit gewinnt, scheint es mir aber, dass das direktere *dass er sie liebt* hier vorzuziehen sei.

Wenn dem so ist (dass beide Varianten gehen), dann bestärkt das allerdings mein Argument, dass es sich bei der Frage "liebte oder liebt" hier nicht (mehr?) um eine grammatische handelt, sondern um eine der (stilistischen) Angemessenheit in bestimmten textlichen Umgebungen.

Comment: _"Hier "dass er sie liebt" zu schreiben, geht einfach nicht."_ Aber es wäre dennoch grammatikalisch korrekt, oder nicht?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Tja... ich wäre gespannt, was andere dazu sagen. Für mich sind wir hier an im Niemandsland zwischen Grammatik und Stilistik, oder besser: in einem von beiden Reichen beanspruchten Grenzstreifen. Im Zweifelsfall vielleicht: Ja, grammatisch schon zulässig, aber stilistisch so verunglückt, dass der Lehrer oder Lektor unbedingt zum Rotstift greift.

Comment: Ich glaube, du mischst hier zwei unterschiedliche Situationen. Dein erstes Beispiel ist direkte Rede, das zweite aber indirekte Rede. Interessanter wäre die Frage, ob „Er sagt, dass er mich lieb*t*“ und „Er sagt, dass er mich lieb*e*“ gleichermaßen gebräuchlich sind.

Comment: Nein. An sich ist das grammatikalisch falsch, oder zumindestens umgangssprachlich. Indirekte Rede steht im Konjunktiv 1.

Comment: @tofro    Ich tue mir schwer damit, "Er sagt, dass er mich liebt" als ***grammatisch*** falsch einzustufen. Diese Form des *dass+Indikativ* ist so verbreitet auch in (sonst?) regelkonformer Umgangssprache, dass es seltsam wäre, dies dann als ständig begangenen grammatischen Fehler zu sehen. Wenn etwas die Regel wird, ist es kaum ein Fehler mehr. Ich komme also immer mehr dazu, dass es hier schlichtweg um das sprachliche Umfeld geht (Textgattung). Eine Form, die in der einen Textgattung richtig, in der anderen falsch ist, würde ich aber nicht mehr als *grammatisch* falsch einstufen.

Comment: Konjunktiv ist in der Umgangssprache halt unbeliebt.

Comment: Dein Roman ist auch nicht im Präsenz geschrieben.

Answer (score 6):

Es hängt vielleicht etwas vom Kontext, bzw. der Intention einer solchen Aussage ab:

> > Er sagt, dass das er mich liebe.

impliziert m.E. einen deutlichen Zweifel an der Aussage von *ihm*, während

> > Er sagt, dass er mich liebt.

zunächst einmal lediglich eine Feststellung zu *seiner* Aussage ist.

---

> und ob hier "liebe" zu benutzen eher unnatüralich/merkwürdig in umgangssprache klingen würde.

Wie es @S.M.Roch im [Kommentar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/41933/er-sagt-dass-er-mich-liebe-liebt/41934#comment104229_41934) ausgedrückt hat, würde man wohl umgangssprachlich in so einem Fall eher

> > Er sagt, dass er mich lieben würde.

oder

> > Er sagt, er würde mich lieben.

verwenden.

Ebenso einfach für die simple Feststellung:

> > Er sagt, er liebt mich.

Grammatikalisch sind beide Formen korrekt.

Comment: Absolut richtig. Vergleiche auch: "Er sagt, dass er mich lieben wuerde" bzw. "Er sagt, dass er mich liebte". Durch die Verwendung von Konjunktiv 2 wird sehr starker Zweifel ausgedrueckt.

Comment: @S.M.Roch Danke für den Konjunktiv 2 (Die Schule ist schon soo lange her). Ich war mir ziemlich sicher, dass dies ein Konjunktiv ist, aber nicht genau welche Form, daher hatte ich es lieber nicht erwähnt.

Comment: Diese Antwort ist falsch. Das erste Beispiel ist Konjunktiv I (_liebe_) und nichts weiter als indirekte Rede. Zweifel an der Aussage besteht erst bei Konjunktiv II (_liebte_), den heute vermutlich viele durch die Ersatzform (_lieben würde_) ausdrücken. Und _liebt_ ist der Indikativ.

Comment: *liebte* ist nicht notwendigerweise Konjunktiv 2. Er liebt sie aber trotzdem nicht (mehr).

Comment: @tofro Gut, das ich nichts von Alledem in meiner Antwort erwähnt habe ;-)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Meintest Du meine Anwort oder den Kommentar? Ich kann nicht erkennen, was an meiner Antwort wirklich falsch sein soll.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Völlig richtig, der Konjunktiv 1 ("er liebe") wird für indirekte Rede verwendet. Allerdings würde man in diesem Fall schon Zweifel ausdrücken, wenn man Konj. 1, d.h. indirekte Rede verwendet. Zumindest meinem Sprachempfinden nach, das natürlich subjektiv ist. Die Verwendung von Konjunktiv 2 ("er würde lieben" / "er liebte") verschärft den Zweifel nochmals.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Möglicherweise ist "Zweifel" nicht der richtige Begriff, oder muss zumindest in einen Kontext gesetzt werden. Dennoch macht aber indirekte Rede im Konjunktiv eben keine Aussage über den Wahrheitsgehalt des Gesagten. "Er sagt, dass er mich liebe." drückt also aus, was er sagt, aber nicht, ob das auch zutrifft (unabhängig davon, dass dieser Ungewissheit durch Verwendung von Konjunktiv II zusätzlich Nachdruck verliehen werden kann). Einem allwissenden Erzähler steht es aber auch frei, "Er sagt, dass er mich liebt." zu sagen, womit wir aber keine indirekte Rede mehr vor uns ...

Comment: ... haben, sondern nur eine Aussage dazu, über welche Tatsache er gesprochen hat. Meines Erachtens lässt sich der Unterschied bei einem Satz wie "Er sagt, dass Kopenhagen die Hauptstadt Dänemarks sei/ist." besser nachvollziehen als an dem persönlich/emotional geprägten Beispiel, das wirkliches Faktenwissen des Erzählers eventuell schwer vorstellbar macht.

Answer (score 2):

Bis auf einen Punkt, den ich hier nachtrage, ist alles geklärt.

Beide Antwortgeber meinen,

> Er sagt, dass er mich liebt.

sei korrekt, ohne jedoch eine Quelle zu nennen. [Hier ist sie](https://books.google.de/books?hl=de&id=1-HBDQAAQBAJ&q=indirekte%20Rede#v=snippet&q=%22der%20Gebrauch%20des%20Konjunktivs%20ist%20in%20der%20indirekten%20Rede%22&f=false).

Ja, es stimmt also. Da die indirekte Rede durch ein redeeinleitendes Verb (hier: »sagt«) gekennzeichnet wird, kann auf den Konjunktiv verzichtet werden.